# How do I validate numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

How to validate a numeric numbers?

Comment: Look here - this has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-variable-whether-is-number-or-string-in-javascript

Comment: do you mean the datatype is number  or string type  number? var strNum = '123';

Answer (score 1):

```
var number_string = document.getElementById("my_input").value;
is_valid = /^[0-9]+$/.test(number_string);
```

Don't forget to server-side validate as well!

Comment: Just for the record, if you want to allow commas or dollar signs just add them after the 9 in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a pretty nice implementation of [isNumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) here.