# javascript isInstanceOf

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to detect if variable is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891937/how-to-detect-if-variable-is-a-string)

```
x = 'myname';
x.intanceOf == String
```

why does the second statement returns false ? how can i check if a variable is string or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false because `intanceOf`[sic] is `undefined`, not a reference to the `String` constructor.

`instanceOf` is an *operator*, not an instance method or property, and is used like this:

```
 "string" instanceof String
```

But this will return false as the literal string is not a `String object` created using the `String` constructor.

So what you really want to do is use the `type` operator

```
typeof "string" == "string"
```

Comment: Exactly! instanceof would work if you explicitly called the String constructor i.e : var x = new String('myname');

Answer (score 1):

Using instanceOf might not be a good idea after all.

> The typeof operator (together with
>   instanceof) is probably the biggest
>   design flaw of JavaScript, as it is
>   near of being completely broken.

See: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof

Instead use **Object.prototype.toString** like so:

```
function is(type, obj) {
    var clas = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && clas === type;
}

is('String', 'test'); // true
is('String', new String('test')); // true
```