# How can I check if a var is a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, variable-types

How can I check if a var is a string in JavaScript?

I've tried this and it doesn't work...

```
var a_string = "Hello, I'm a string.";

if (a_string typeof 'string') {
    // this is a string
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This is also a duplicate of [Check if a variable is a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

You were close:

```
if (typeof a_string === 'string') {
    // this is a string
}
```

---

On a related note: the above check won't work if a string is created with `new String('hello')` as the type will be `Object` instead. There are complicated solutions to work around this, but it's better to just avoid creating strings  that way, ever.

Comment: Guys, I really would give an accepted answer to both of you, but I can't, all I can do is +1 to both, than give the accepted answer at who is more near to my specific problem, that I've not fully explained.

Comment: this worked for me
`if(typeof(str) === typeof(String())) `

Comment: String() returns a string but new String() returns an object

Answer (score 83):

The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) operator isn't an infix (so the LHS of your example doesn't make sense).

You need to use it like so...

```
if (typeof a_string == 'string') {
    // This is a string.
}
```

Remember, `typeof` is an operator, not a function. Despite this, you will see `typeof(var)` being used a lot in the wild. This makes as much sense as `var a = 4 + (1)`.

Also, you may as well use `==` (equality comparison operator) since both operands are `String`s (`typeof` **always** returns a `String`), JavaScript is defined to perform the same steps had I used `===` (strict comparison operator).

As [Box9 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286542/how-can-i-check-if-a-var-is-a-string-in-javascript/6286551#6286551), this [won't detect](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ZK7AB/) a instantiated `String` object.

You can detect for that with....

```
var isString = str instanceof String;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/NLdrk/).

...or...

```
var isString = str.constructor == String;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/STvLj/).

**But** this won't work in a multi `window` environment (think `iframe`s).

You can get around this with...

```
var isString = Object.prototype.toString.call(str) == '[object String]';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/EXLxA/).

But again, (as [Box9 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286542/how-can-i-check-if-a-var-is-a-string-in-javascript/6286551#6286551)), you are better off just using the literal `String` format, e.g. `var str = 'I am a string';`.

[Further Reading](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-typeof).

Comment: @Box9 No worries, I'm rep capped anyway :P

Comment: @alex I am now too :o (10 more minutes!)

Comment: @RobG Rep capped is when you have gained the maximum rep for one 24 hour period. After that, upvotes do not count towards your reputation.

Comment: Is it not possible to check if a variable is a string by simply testing for the presence of a member that only strings have? For example: `if(myVar.toUpperCase) alert('I am a string');`? See: http://jsfiddle.net/tb3t4nsx/

Comment: @ingredient_15939 it's not really a good way... because of `{ toUpperCase: '' }`

Answer (score 16):

Combining the previous answers provides these solutions:

```
if (typeof str == 'string' || str instanceof String)
```

or

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(str) == '[object String]'
```

Answer (score 8):

Following expression returns *true*:

```
'qwe'.constructor === String
```

Following expression returns *true*:

```
typeof 'qwe' === 'string'
```

Following expression returns *false* (sic!):

```
typeof new String('qwe') === 'string'
```

Following expression returns *true*:

```
typeof new String('qwe').valueOf() === 'string'
```

Best and right way (*imho*):

```
if (someVariable.constructor === String) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now days I believe it's preferred to use a function form of typeof() so...

```
if(filename === undefined || typeof(filename) !== "string" || filename === "") {
   console.log("no filename aborted.");
   return;
}
```

Comment: there is no function form of `typeof`, you're just controlling order of operations with those parentheses. Some people may find it more readable in certain circumstances.

Comment: @Jonz What did you mean by "controlling order of operations"? Thanks.

Comment: I think later I realized you can check the constructor and prefer it as it in theory I thought would be faster but it's not faster? Example number 4 here show the parentheses usage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof it's definately more readable and less for a compiler parsing to consider. My guess on the 'order' is possibly a speed issue or related to how the compiler loads the argument stack, I'm not sure.

Comment: @a20 order of operations describes the order in which operations are executed for statements that contain multiple operations. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence - parentheses (Operating grouping) have the highest operator precedence and are therefore evaluated first.

In this case, the parentheses around `filename` only group a single statement, and are therefore useless and extraneous. It's a good thing this answer has a score of 0 because it's wrong, misleading, and unhelpful; it would be better if it had a negative score.

Comment: Very informative thanks for the link. So the parentheses are checked & run first? so that should run right away without checking next for other ways of calling aka without parentheses, which would be steps later and slower? no? what am I not understanding about the runtime compiler there.

Comment: I prefer the constructor method now days, even if the performance monitors still don't say it's faster I figure it should be (and maybe I'm waiting until it does ha ha.)

Answer (score 0):

check for null or undefined in all cases a_string

```
if (a_string && typeof a_string === 'string') {
    // this is a string and it is not null or undefined.
}
```

Comment: `typeof null` and `typeof undefined` will never return `'string'`, so `typeof a_string` is enough. Sorry for necroposting