# Filter out for arrays in my function in underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The code below runs if profile.team_member_designations is an array. I want to have a condition added in to filter or check if profile_member_designations is an array, because if it's a string, I DO NOT want the code to run. Essentially, right before the map function, I want to filter out for arrays only to run through the code. How do I do this?

JS

```
   var getTeamDesignations = function(profile) {
        //Designations for a single team member                                                                                                          
        var teamDesignations = [];
        if (profile.team_members) {
            teamDesignations = _.chain(profile.team_members)
                .map(_.property('team_member_designations'))
                .flatten()
                .uniq()
                .value();
        }
        return teamDesignations;
    };
```

Comment: There's no `profile.team_member_designations` in your code. But the easiest way is using the `typeof` operator: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6286542/215552

Comment: `if (profile.team_members && Array.isArray(profile.team_members.team_member_designations)) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want want something like this.

```
var getTeamDesignations = function(profile) {
    //Designations for a single team member                                                                                                          
    var teamDesignations = [];
    if (profile.team_members) {
        teamDesignations = _.chain(profile.team_members)
            .filter(_.compose(_.isArray, _.property('team_member_designations')))
            .map(_.property('team_member_designations'))
            .flatten()
            .uniq()
            .value();
    }
    return teamDesignations;
};
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Could you explain why _.compose was needed along with the filter method?

Comment: It could have been written as:
`.filter(tm => _.isArray(tm.team_member_designations)`

The underscore docs describe _.compose as [the composition of a list of functions, where each function consumes the return value of the function that follows.](http://underscorejs.org/#compose) You will often see this notated as `g(f())` - or in this case `_.isArray(_.property('team_member_designations')(team_member))`

TLDR - I am using _.compose to create a predicate function to pass to _.filter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace if condition as follows:

```
if (profile.team_members && (profile.team_members instanceof Array)){
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Use the [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```
var getTeamDesignations = function(profile) {
        //Designations for a single team member                                                                                                          
        var teamDesignations = [];
        if (profile.team_members && Array.isArray(profile.team_members)) {
            teamDesignations = _.chain(profile.team_members)
                .map(_.property('team_member_designations'))
                .flatten()
                .uniq()
                .value();
        }
        return teamDesignations;
    };
```

Array.isArray returns true when the parameter is an array. It has good [browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp) as well.