# How to get all properties who are text in this object?

Tags: javascript, object

[edit] it's not a dupe because every properties are `string` when I tried `typeof list[x]`  I want to get only the one who are `x: text`

I'm trying to get all the properties who are `text` but I can't achieve it. I don't know why the snippet is not working I made a mistake but I don't find where...
My object is like this:[image]

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e){
 var list = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes[1].childNodes;
  for (var x in list) {
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      if(list[x] === "text"){
         console.log(list[x]);
      }else{
         console.log("no text");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(list)
}
```

```html
<button id="a">click</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />

<!--entity cadvisor2-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cadvisor2</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't you want to be checking `nodeType` not `typeof`? E.g. `if (x.nodeType === 3)` (3 is the number which represents text nodes).

Comment: @evolutionxbox but I think my loop is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a var is a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286542/how-can-i-check-if-a-var-is-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) of an element which returns 'text' for text tags.

For all properties, check the [Element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). [SVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement) inherits from it.

Answer (score 1):

It shows correct text: `cadvisor` and `cadvisor2`

by changing code to `svg.getElementsByTagName('text')`

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e){
 var target = document.getElementById("target");
 var list = target.getElementsByTagName('text');
 
 for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
   console.log(list[i].textContent);
 }
 
}
```

```html
<button id="a">click</button>
<svg id="target" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentscripttype="application/ecmascript" contentstyletype="text/css" height="555px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1181px;height:555px;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1181 555" width="1181px" zoomAndPan="magnify"><defs><filter height="300%" id="f491e1k" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1"><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"></feGaussianBlur><feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"></feColorMatrix><feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"></feOffset><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"></feBlend></filter></defs>
<g>
<!--entity cadvisor-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="97" x="133.675" y="8"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="210.675" y="13"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="15"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="208.675" y="19"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="57" x="148.675" y="41.3027">cadvisor</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />

<!--entity cadvisor2-->
<rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f491e1k)" height="46.29" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="104" x="433.175" y="377"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="10" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="15" x="517.175" y="382"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="384"></rect>
<rect fill="#FEFECE" height="2" style="stroke: #A80036; stroke-width: 1.5;" width="4" x="515.175" y="388"></rect>
<text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="64" x="448.175" y="410.3027">cadvisor2</text>
<path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I made changes and show correct text. If it still helps =)

Comment: yes it would works like this, I used an other way but it still a good approach