# How can I compare two hex values?

Tags: javascript

I need to compare two hex values that are coming from a xml tag attribute field, I'm trying this:

```
var fill = $(this).attr( "fill" );
// console.log( fill.toString(16) );
if ( fill === "#FF00FF" )
```

But is not working any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it redundant to do a `toString()` when jQuery's `attr` already returns a string?

Comment: I'm doing toString just to see what I get in the console, I'm not using the value still the if statement fails

Comment: Your code should work assuming the "fill" attribute looks like "#FF00FF", hash included.

Comment: Anyways, did you try to check what `fill` is? like `typeof fill`? did you try to `console.log(fill)`? what does it result to?

Comment: it results in plain #FF00FF and other hex values

Comment: typeof fill is string but the if fails

Comment: you should use typeof:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-variable-whether-is-number-or-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr` returns a string, there's no need to call `toString` on it (and the argument will be ignored, because `String`'s `toString` doesn't take an argument).

Your code is assuming a couple of things:

1. That the attribute comes back in #hex form (if it's a color value, this is not reliably true cross-browser).
2. That it will be in all upper case.

Not knowing what you see when you log the value, I'll just address the second part:

```
var fill = $(this).attr( "fill" );
if ( fill.toUpperCase() === "#FF00FF" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use 2 equal signs there, try this...

```
var fill = $(this).attr( "fill" );
if ( fill == "#FF00FF" )
```

If that doesn't work, then you probably not identifying $(this)

Comment: *"I think you have to use 2 equal signs there"* No. `attr` returns a string, so we don't need type coercion (it's almost always better not to rely on type coercion anyway, the rules are a bit complex).

Comment: Working now, I wonder by the === fails if both are of string type?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez: It ought not to. What happens if you `console.log(typeof fill)`?

Comment: I have run into that a lot, and now i just rely on the == instead of === if the values can look the same, but not necessarily both be the same type of variable.

Answer (score 0):

If fill is a color, then it might be returned in RGB-format. And when you log it you write `toString()`. Either compare it with a RGB-value or compare it with a string as `fill.toString(16)`