# Whats wrong here, why is innerHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I wanted to ask why innerHTML is not working in the following code:

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = localStorage["mytext"];
```

The element with the id text is a div element. localStorage is giving me the right String if I use it with alert, what could the error be?

Comment: Hard to tell with so few elements. Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful to try and diagnose the problem. Are you sure `getElementById` is matching an element?

Comment: What browser? Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Are you rying to place text inside a Textbox? if so set the value, dont use innerHTML..
Thats about the only way I can see this failing assuming the element exists an the value to be placed is not null

Comment: @SajjanSarkar *The element with the id text is a **div** element*

Comment: Please make a sample at jsfiddle or jsbin so we can see a full, working example.  Your JS could be included BEFORE the div is in the DOM, or there could be a JS error, or.... just too many possible issues imho.

Comment: @SaschaMayr: What kind of jsfiddle is that? The code is working. `localStorage["mytext"]` hasn't even been defined.

Comment: @SaschaMayr Please read the instructions for jsfiddle before posting it... You're not supposed to put any tag of a greater or equal level than <body>

Comment: i replaced the localstorage thing with "test" and it works.. ur array has no value..

Comment: i think jsfiddle executes Javascript on document load, so the problem (explained in my answer) will not occur

Comment: @lostsource It does when the "onload" option is set, as it is in this case.

Comment: works - http://jsfiddle.net/vZbpg/3/

Comment: Yes, i think the problem somewhere else..maybe DIV not yet added to DOM when the script executes..

Comment: innerText is not valid in Firefox. use textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the div exists before trying to reference it,

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("mytext");
},false);
```

That will wait for the document to load before doing any modifications

Comment: +1, you're probs right judging from the fiddle. You should change it to use `getItem` instead of accessing it via brackets, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the localStorage["text"] really returns a string? Maybe this link might help you to check the if it's really a string.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729103/1873758