# javascript and test for number

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

I am using JS in a riak map reduce job.   I have a number I want to map and needs to be a number.

if I have a variable:

```
 var wp=sfggz5341&& or var=100
```

How can if test if number?

e.g.

```
if wp==Number:    
    OK 
else:    
    pass
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number), [Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for details):

```
var wp = "sfggz53141";
if (typeof wp === "number") {
    // number here
} else if (typeof wp === "string") {
    // string here
}
```

Comment: if `wp` is `'12345'`, `typeof wp` still would be `'string'`

Comment: @KooiInc - yes, because `'12345'` is a string, not a number.  the OP asked if it `was` a number, not if it could be converted into a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can test using: `if (!isNaN(+wp))`. In other words, convert the 'may be number' to number (using the `+` operator. If it can't be converted, the result is `NaN`. So `!isNaN(...)` means it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `isNaN()` or [`isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).

The `isNumeric()` can be used, but fails in following cases:

```
// Whitespace strings:
IsNumeric(' ') == true;
IsNumeric('\t\t') == true;
IsNumeric('\n\r') == true;

// Number literals:
IsNumeric(-1) == false;
IsNumeric(0) == false;
IsNumeric(1.1) == false;
IsNumeric(8e5) == false;
```

So the best way is:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/462627

Answer (score -1):

You can use `!NaN(wp)` to check if the string is a number.

Answer (score -1):

try to use
       `isNaN()`

This function returns true if the value is NaN, and false if not.