# what is the best way to check variable type in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function saveName (firstName) {
    function capitalizeName () {
        return firstName.toUpperCase();
    }
    var capitalized = capitalizeName();console.log(capitalized instanceof String);
    return capitalized; 
}
console.log(saveName("Robert")); // Returns "ROBERT"
</script>
```

Question:

I want to check the type of capitalized , so I use `capitalized instanceof String`? But it shows: `false` in console, I do not want to try `capitalized instanceof Function`, `Object`...It will take too much time, so what is the best way to detect a variable type?

Comment: Because a string literal isn't an object of `String` type. See `typeof capitalized`

Comment: check my one-liner answer :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The best way is to use the `typeof` keyword.

```
typeof "hello" // "string"
```

The `typeof` operator maps an operand to one of eight possible values:

- `"string"`
- `"number"`
- `"object"`
- `"function"`
- `"undefined"`
- `"boolean"`
- `"symbol"`
- `"bigint"`

The `instanceof` method tests if the provided function's prototype is in the object's prototype chain.

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) does a pretty good job of summing up JavaScript's types.

Comment: `typeof new String("hello") == "object"` but it can benefit from all the same characteristics of `string`.  It would be safest to say `typeof x == "string" || x instance of String`

Comment: I suppose you're correct, although in practice I almost never see `new String("hello")` used.

Comment: `function` is not a built-in type. A function is an object. And `null` is a type too. See [ECMAScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), sections 8 and 11.4.3

Comment: What about `array`?

Comment: @SeanH Like `function`, `array` also isn't a built-in type—`typeof array` returns `"object"`. However, if you want to know something is an array, you can use `Array.isArray(array)`.

Answer (score 21):

use `typeof();`

example:

```
> typeof "foo"
"string"
> typeof true
"boolean"
> typeof 42
"number"
```

So you can do:

```
if(typeof bar === 'string') {
   //whatever
}
```

Keep in mind that, typeof is only good for returning the "primitive" types, number, boolean, object, string. You can also use instanceof to test if an object is of a specific type.

```
function MyObj(prop) {
  this.prop = prop;
}

var obj = new MyObj(10);

console.log(obj instanceof MyObj && obj instanceof Object); // outputs true
```

Answer (score 13):

2021+ one liner answer.

My favourite way is **not to** use `typeof`

*Why?*
because it doesn't give true type for other than boolean, string, number & function.

*Then what?*
Here is small utility function using `Object.prototype`

```js
var trueTypeOf = (obj) => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase()
```

Results:

```js
trueTypeOf([]); // array
trueTypeOf({}); // object
trueTypeOf(''); // string
trueTypeOf(new Date()); // date
trueTypeOf(1); // number
trueTypeOf(function () {}); // function
trueTypeOf(/test/i); // regexp
trueTypeOf(true); // boolean
trueTypeOf(null); // null
trueTypeOf(); // undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is using `typeof`

```
typeof "blahha"
```

I made a function with help of jQuery library code,   [jQuery library type method github link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L403) .

```
var getType = (function() {

    var objToString = ({}).toString ,
        typeMap     = {},
        types = [ 
          "Boolean", 
          "Number", 
          "String",                
          "Function", 
          "Array", 
          "Date",
          "RegExp", 
          "Object", 
          "Error"
        ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < types.length ; i++ ){
        typeMap[ "[object " + types[i] + "]" ] = types[i].toLowerCase();
    };    

    return function( obj ){
        if ( obj == null ) {
            return String( obj );
        }
        // Support: Safari <= 5.1 (functionish RegExp)
        return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
            typeMap[ objToString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
            typeof obj;
    }
}());
```

You can call it as `getType("Hello")`

Answer (score 2):

typeof capitalized == 'string'

Answer (score 2):

The **getVarType** method (below) works for almost all variables. [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsn76/3/).  It first uses the very fast **typeof** for cases where the results are reliable.  Then it uses a more expensive **toString** method for other cases.  Finally, if it is dealing with a named object (as returned by Firefox for objects like document.location) it checks for Array-like objects and reports them as arrays.

In comparison, **typeof** is embarrassingly poor.  typeof([]) returns 'object', typeof(new Number()) returns object.  It also returns 'object' for many other variables that aren't (for practical purposes) objects.  See the fiddle results for a comparison.

```
  // Begin public utility /getVarType/
  // Returns 'Function', 'Object', 'Array',
  // 'String', 'Number', 'Null', 'Boolean', or 'Undefined'
  //
  getVarType = (function () {
    var typeof_map = {
      'undefined' : 'Undefined',
      'boolean'   : 'Boolean',
      'number'    : 'Number',
      'string'    : 'String',
      'function'  : 'Function',

      'Undefined' : 'Undefined',
      'Null'      : 'Null',
      'Boolean'   : 'Boolean',
      'Number'    : 'Number',
      'String'    : 'String',
      'Function'  : 'Function',
      'Array'     : 'Array',
      'StyleSheetList' : 'Array'
    };

    return function( data ) {
      var type, type_str;

      if ( data === null      ) { return 'Null'; }
      if ( data === undefined ) { return 'Undefined'; }

      type     = typeof( data );
      type_str = typeof_map[ type ];

      if ( type_str ) { return type_str; }

      type = {}.toString.call( data ).slice( 8, -1 );
      return typeof_map[ type ]
        || ( data instanceof Array ? 'Array' :
        ( data.propertyIsEnumerable(0) && data.length !== undefined
          ? 'Array' : 'Object' )
        );
    };
  }());
  // End public utility /getVarType/
```

The only possible failure mode happens if you are testing a named array that is empty (e.g. an empty enumerable DOM object besides the StyleSheetList).  But on could add those to the type_of_map as needed.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

## ES-Next version with support `BigInt` & `Symbol`

```js
"use strict";

/**
 *
 * @author xgqfrms
 * @license MIT
 * @copyright xgqfrms
 * @created 2020-06-09
 * @modified
 *
 * @description js data type checker
 * @augments
 * @example
 * @link
 *
 */


const dataTypeChecker = (data, debug = false) => {
  const log = console.log;
  let result = ``;
  const typeString = Object.prototype.toString.call(data);
  result = typeString.replace(/\[object /gi, ``).replace(/\]/gi, ``);
  if(debug) {
    log(`true type`, result)
  }
  return result;
};



/*

export default dataTypeChecker;

export {
  dataTypeChecker,
};

*/
```

> test

```js
const dataTypeChecker = (data, debug = false) => {
  const log = console.log;
  let result = ``;
  const typeString = Object.prototype.toString.call(data);
  // const typeString = Object.prototype.toString.apply(data);
  result = typeString.replace(/\[object /gi, ``).replace(/\]/gi, ``);
  if(!debug) {
    log(`true type`, result)
  }
  return result;
};



const obj = {};
const func = () => {};


dataTypeChecker(NaN)
//"[object Number]"
dataTypeChecker(undefined)
//"[object Undefined]"
dataTypeChecker(true)
//"[object Boolean]"
dataTypeChecker({})
//"[object Object]"
dataTypeChecker(func)
//"[object Function]"
dataTypeChecker(obj)
//"[object Object]"
dataTypeChecker(Symbol())
//"[object Symbol]"
dataTypeChecker(null)
//"[object Null]"
dataTypeChecker(123)
//"[object Number]"
dataTypeChecker(BigInt(1n))
//"[object BigInt]"


// true type Number
// true type Undefined
// true type Boolean
// true type Object
// true type Function
// true type Object
// true type Symbol
// true type Null
// true type Number
// true type BigInt
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 //-- difference constructor & typeof --//

 const fx = () => {}
 const arr = []
 const obj = {}
 
 console.log( fx.constructor == Function ) // true
 console.log( arr.constructor == Array ) // true
 console.log( arr.constructor == Object ) // false
 console.log( obj.constructor == Object ) // true
 console.log( obj.constructor == Array ) // false
 
 console.log( typeof obj ) // object
 console.log( typeof arr ) // object
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).