# javascript convert strings 'true' or 'false' to boolean and return true

Tags: javascript

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript) question, adn also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440517/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-variable-type-in-javascript) but still my problem persists. I need to store in Mysql in VARCHAR field different data, like `true`,  `false`, numbers and other strings. When I get 'true' or 'false' strings from my DB, in my JS code I need to check that it is `boolean` type, hence return `true` both for `true` and `false` values, ore something like `typeof Boolean === true`, in other case return `false`. I tried many variants from the above mentioned questions, but all solutions returned `true` if the value was `true` and `false` if the values was `false` which is wrong for me. Any ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `if (value === "true" || value === "false")`?

Comment: yes, maybe there is some more elegant way?

Comment: What did you try? Show your code and your result please

Comment: What do you mean by "more elegant?" This seems like the clearest, most straightforward way to do what you're asking (determine whether the value is one of "true" or "false").

Comment: Do the above if it's a string. If it's coming out of the database as a boolean then just `typeof value === 'boolean'`.

Comment: @SamHH Per the question, it's always a string. (It's a VARCHAR field in the database.)

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, from js, you've got Booleans or strings ? Why don't you simply convert all this data into JSON server-side, and then use JSON.parse from js ?

Comment: @smarx, just post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if the value is one of "true" or "false":

```
if (value === "true" || value === "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value first, if it should be a boolean and then convert it or return the original value.

```
value = value === 'true' || value === 'false' ? value === 'true' : value
```