# how many ways to check if x is integer and which one is most efficient?

Tags: javascript, integer

I already checked [what is the best way to check variable type in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440517/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-variable-type-in-javascript)
question on So but didn't found answer of my question.

In javascript how many ways to find if input type is integer? which one is efficient?

I was looking the way to find the integer in javascript and found number of ways to do this:

1. Using `typeof`

```js
function isInteger(x) 
{ 
   return (typeof x === 'number') && (x % 1 === 0); 
   
}
console.log(isInteger(10));
console.log(isInteger(10.1))
```

2. Using `parseInt`

```js
function isInteger(x) 
{ 
   return parseInt(x, 10) === x; 
   
}
console.log(isInteger(10));
console.log(isInteger(10.1));
```

3. Using `Math.round`

```js
function isInteger(x)
{ 
  return Math.round(x) === x; 
  
}
console.log(isInteger(10));
console.log(isInteger(10.1));
```

Is there any other way to find the type of Integer and which one will be most efficient for consider small to large integer values.

Comment: `parseInt()` is an awkward way of doing it because the first thing it does is convert the number to a string.

Comment: Try running speed test too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am concluding answer for this question after some resarch

From **ECMAscript 6** which introduces a new `Number.isInteger()` function for precisely this purpose.

However, prior to **ECMAScript 6**, this is a bit more complicated, since no equivalent of the `Number.isInteger()` method is provided.

The simplest and cleanest `pre-ECMAScript-6` solution (which is also sufficiently robust to return false even if a non-numeric value such as a string or null is passed to the function) would be the following use of the `bitwise XOR operator`:

```
function isInteger(x) 
{ 
  return (x ^ 0) === x; 
}
```

Others like `Math.round()` ,`typeof` and `parseInt` can be used also to find the `Integer`.

> While this `parseInt`-based approach will work well for many values of `x`, once `x` becomes quite large, it will fail to work properly. The problem is that `parseInt()` coerces its first parameter to a string before parsing digits. Therefore, once the number becomes sufficiently large, its string representation will be presented in exponential form (e.g., `1e+21`). Accordingly, `parseInt()` will then try to parse `1e+21`, but will stop parsing when it reaches the e character and will therefore return a value of `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The most intuitive one is [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger), at least in my opinion

```js
function isInteger(x)
{ 
  return Number.isInteger(x); 
  
}
console.log(isInteger(10)); // Output: True
console.log(isInteger(10.1)); // Output: False
```

**Edit**

As for efficiency, I created a benchmark on jsben.ch where I try all your methods and mine, you can see for yourself ;)

[Link](http://jsben.ch/OiARp)

Comment: why any specific reason?Is it suitable for long Integer values?

Comment: I'm afraid this is unsupported on IE however (see it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) )

Comment: Too bad it isn't supported in IE.
I think it's the most intuitive because it explicitly says what it's doing instead of hiding behind some mathematical or programmatical hack.

Comment: in your opinion Number.isInteger() is best however your benchmark says typeof.i got confuse

Comment: @NullPointer Hmm, I ran it a couple of times and it seems to be quite inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the speed of each code at [JSBEN.CH](http://jsben.ch)

```
typeof => 347 ms

parseInt => 338 ms

Math.round => 367 ms
```

Interestingly, `parseInt` is the fastest way!

It's only the speed comparison. Go with `Number.isInteger(x)` instead! It's the instinctive & fastest of all.

Comment: by pointy in comments>parseInt() is an awkward way of doing it because the first thing it does is convert the number to a string

Comment: Then again, use Number.isInteger only IF you don't care about IE compatibility (unsupported there). Besides, thanks a lot for the bench.

Comment: parseInt also works for string so Number.isInteger should be used and adding a polyfill for IE would be the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your propositions seem fine, but let's add for completion the polyfill Mozilla puts forward :

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) && 
    Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```