# How can I check if variable in java script is type of a particular object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I check if variable in java script is type of a particular object? What will be the result of this

```
var myvalue = "200"+50+44;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The **`typeof`** operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

2) The result will be `2005044`

I think you're trying like this

```
parseInt("200", 10)+50+44 // returns 294
```

Check **[`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** for more information.

Comment: It's easy to get the wrong base with `parseInt` so it's advisable to define base as well, ie: `parseInt("200", 10)` (here base-10).

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Yes, you're right because there is chance of having **prefixed '0'(which is considered as octal)**.  I missed it, I have updated it.   Thank you for your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The **type** can be checked with the `typeof` operator.

```
typeof myvalue === "number"
```

The possible types are "number", "string", "object", "undefined".  This has a few problems though.

- `typeof someArray === "object"`
- `typeof null === "object"`

---

The better way is compare constructors.

- `someArray.constructor === Array`
- `someNumber.constructor === Number`

You do however need to check if it's null or undefined, because neither have a constructor property.

- `someThing != null && someThing.constructor === SomeConstructor`