# Sortable table columns with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to sort a table of data which is populated from a JSON source.  The code I have is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PurchasesCtrl">
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="first">
                <th class="first" ng:click="changeSorting(purchases.date)">Date</th>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting(purchases.text)">Description</th>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting(purchases.price)">Amount</th>
                <th ng:click="changeSorting(purchases.availability)">Status</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="purchase in purchases.data">
                <td class="first">{{purchase.date}}</td>
                <td>{{purchase.text}}</td>
                <td>{{purchase.price}}</td>
                <td>{{purchase.availability}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.factory("Purchases", function(){
    var Purchases = {};

    Purchases.data = [
        {
            date: "10/05/2012",
            text: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
            price: "£123.45",
            availability: "1 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
        },
        {
            date: "24/05/2012",
            text: "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
            price: "£234.56",
            availability: "2 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
        },
        {
            date: "20/05/2012",
            text: "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
            price: "£345.67",
            availability: "3 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
        }
    ];
    return Purchases;
});

function PurchasesCtrl($scope, Purchases){
    $scope.purchases = Purchases;

    $scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
        var sort = $scope.sort;

        if (sort.column == column) {
            sort.descending = !sort.descending;
        } else {
            sort.column = column;
            sort.descending = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7czsM/1/

As you can see I've tried to add a click function to the table headers to call a function that sorts the data, but it's not working.

I've seen an example of this kind of thing which does work, here: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/js64b/14/, but when I try to apply the same kind of thing to my scenario it breaks very quickly; for example, I tried adding the table headers programatically in JSON by adding the following:

```
var Purchases = {};

Purchases.head = [
        {
            date: "Date",
            text: "Text column",
            price: "Price column",
            availability: "Availability column"
        }

    Purchases.data = [
        {
            date: "10/05/2012",
            text: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
            price: "£123.45",
            availability: "1 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
        },
```

This just prevents anything from working, but I thought it would be possible to add multiple sets of data to an Angular variable?

I'm a total new-comer to Angular so I'm really stuck with this.  Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You forgot to take the `$scope.sort` function.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't follow?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gweur/

sza is right, you did forget the $scope.sort object, but you are also missing the orderBy filter in your ng-repeat

```
|orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending
```

Additionally, you'll need to explicitly pass the column name to the changeSorting() function, like

```
ng-click="changeSorting('text')"
```

not sure if there is a different way you can handle this.

Finally, ng-click is the correct syntax for the version of AngularJS you are using.

Answer (score 8):

Another very good example of making table sortable

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/js64b/14/

```
<th ng:repeat="(i,th) in head" ng:class="selectedCls(i)" ng:click="changeSorting(i)">{{th}}</th>

scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
    var sort = scope.sort;
    if (sort.column == column) {
        sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
        sort.column = column;
        sort.descending = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution. I also wrap the whole thing to a directive. The only dependency is UI.Bootstrap.pagination, which did a great job on pagination.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mVVSLl?p=preview)

Here is the [github source code.](https://github.com/maxisam/Angular-XUI/tree/master/xuiTable)

Comment: Your sorting is kind of messed up. Click in the name col and you will see: "name 1, name 10, name 11, name 12" and so on (when it should be "name 1, name 2, name 3, ...")

Comment: It is base on string. you can create you own sorting method to replace it. The idea is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use #ngTasty as simple table directive.
github : https://github.com/Zizzamia/ng-tasty
docs : http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your boilerplate code for AngularJS, specifically setting up your Controller and Factory, might have had had a syntax error.

Here is an example of your data working and expanded on your table column sorting method. Since AngularJS is good at processing javascript data-structures for displaying in HTML, you can just rearrange the javascript-arrays in memory, and AngularJS picks up on the changes. **This example allows clicking the headers of the table, which will trigger a sorting based on that columns data type. If it is already sorted on that column, it will reverse-sort the column.** The type detection is done through the presented isNumeric() function, and one two-tiny tweaks:

1. Added checks if inputting on the '#' symbol as a header and sorts as a number in the toggleSort method. This can easily be removed by users if preferred.
2. When toggleSort attempts to sort alphabetically, if it catches a TypeError it then switches to sorting on numbers.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.factory("Purchases", function() {
  var Purchases = {};

  Purchases.data = [{
    date: "10/05/2012",
    text: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
    price: "£123.45",
    availability: "1 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
  }, {
    date: "24/05/2012",
    text: "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
    price: "£234.56",
    availability: "2 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
  }, {
    date: "20/05/2012",
    text: "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor",
    price: "£345.67",
    availability: "3 Available until 10th Dec 2013"
  }];
  return Purchases;
});

myApp.controller("PurchasesCtrl", function($scope, Purchases) {
  $scope.purchases = Purchases.data;

  // Dynamically get the entry headers to use with displaying the nested data via header-key lookups
  // Assumes all lines contain same key-text data
  $scope.purchasesHeaderKeys = []; // Contains only the key-data, not the values
  for (var key in $scope.purchases[0]) {
    if ($scope.purchases[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      $scope.purchasesHeaderKeys.push(key);
    }
  }


  /**
   * Determine if the input value is a number or not.
   * @param n The input value to be checked for numeric status.
   * @returns true if parameter is numeric, or false otherwise.
   * 
   * This method uses the following evaluations to determine if input is a numeric:
   * 
   *   (5); // true  
   *   ('123'); // true  
   *   ('123abc'); // false  
   *   ('q345'); // false
   *   (null); // false
   *   (""); // false
   *  ([]); // false
   *   ('   '); // false
   *   (true); // false
   *   (false); // false
   *   (undefined); // false
   *   (new String('')); // false
   * 
   * @author C.D. (modified by)
   * @original https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421988/10930451
   * 
   */
  function isNumeric(n) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && !isNaN(n - 0) && n !== null && n !== "") {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Column Sort Method (generic). Sort based on target column header or reverse sort if already selected on that.
   * @param dataSource The array of JSON data to be sorted
   * @param headers The array of JSON object-keys (table column headers) to be referenced
   * @param index The target JSON object-key to sort the table columns based upon
   * 
   * @author C.D.
   */
  $scope.lastSortIndex = 0;
  $scope.changeSorting = function(dataSource, headers, index) {
    if ($scope.lastSortIndex === index) {
      dataSource.reverse();
    } else {
      var key = headers[index];
      if (key === "#" || isNumeric(dataSource[key])) { // Compare as numeric or on '#' sign
        dataSource.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a[key]) - parseFloat(b[key]));
      } else // Compare as Strings
      {
        try { // Attempt to sort as Strings
          dataSource.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name === 'TypeError') { // Catch type error, actually sort as Numeric
            dataSource.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a[key]) - parseFloat(b[key]));
          }
        }
      }
      $scope.lastSortIndex = index;
      $scope.reverseSorted = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>AngularJS - Hello World</title>


  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PurchasesCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="header in purchasesHeaderKeys">
       <a ng-click="changeSorting(purchases, purchasesHeaderKeys, $index)">{{ header }}</a>
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  
    <tbody>
     <!-- Data is nested, so double-repeat to extract and display -->
     <tr ng-repeat="row in purchases" >
      <td ng-repeat="key in purchasesHeaderKeys">
       {{row[key]}}
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have put together a working [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/b9dFSiE5lR2n1WoxqH24?p=preview) to demonstrate. Just click on the headers and they will sort the array in memory, where AngularJS will pick up on the changes and refresh that portion of the DOM.