# How to test if a string is a not number

Tags: javascript, string, text, extendscript

I'm trying to verify if a string is text or number.
Could not find a proper way to verify.
Could you please advice?

Here is my problem:

```
var myNumber = "006";
var myText = "1. This is not a number";

isNaN(myNumber); // false
isNaN(myText); // false

I tried also:
isNaN(myNumber.split('.')[1]);  // true
isNaN(myText.split('.')[1]); // true

parseInt(myNumber); // 6
parseInt(myText); // 1
```

What I would like to achieve would be to find when a string can be converted to a number (see myNumber). In case that the string is actually a text, how to spot it with javascript?

Could you please advise?

Comment: Try to see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript

Comment: In my opinion the easiest way is to multiply the variable by 1 and check if the result is NaN, i.e. `isNaN( myVariable * 1 )`

Comment: `isNaN(myNumber)` returns true, not false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Comment: Please don't edit post titles to add solved. If an answer here has solved your issue, I suggest you mark an answer as resolved, otherwise leave a comment (Or even better, answer your own question) to direct others on how you solved your solution (As to help readers in the future). See this post for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question correctly I may have a solution but this will work even if the string is a number so here you go:

```
var yourNumber="55";
if(yourNumber*1==yourNumber){
 alert("It's a number");
}else{alert("it's not a number");}
```

Comment: This one does not work for me, as I'm using ExtendScript.
What about the string yourNumber="55. bla bla bla" ?

Answer (score 1):

If `parseInt()` is not working for your desired results, you can try `Number` constructor. It gives you `NaN` for non-numbers, which you can verify by using `isNaN()` function.

```js
var myNumber = "006";
var myText = "1. This is not a number";

console.log( Number(myNumber) );
console.log( Number(myText) );
```

Or you can use regular expressions:

```js
 var myNumber = "006";
 var myText = "1. This is not a number";

 var numRegex = /^\d+$/;

 console.log( numRegex.test(myNumber) );
 console.log( numRegex.test(myText) );
```

Comment: I think the solution with `Number` constructor is the best!

Comment: Thanks @DmitryMasley

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

```
function isNumber(num){
  return /^(\d+)?(\.)?\d+$/.test(num);
}

isNumber("006") // true
isNumber(".6") // true
isNumber("1 not a number") // false
isNumber("23.63") // true
isNumber("23.6.3") // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]*$');
var myNumber = "006";
var myText = "1. This is not a number";
reg.test(myNumber) //true
reg.test(myText) //false
```

Comment: Hi pawel, thanks for this. I was also trying this way, but I forgot to include the $ sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if text is a number using isNaN function:

```js
var myNumber = "006";
var myText = "1. This is not a number";

console.log(myNumber + ': ' + !isNaN(myNumber));
console.log(myText + ': ' + !isNaN(myText));
```

Comment: Yes, it works in the browser. I forgot to say I'm using Adobe ExtendScript.

Answer (score 0):

**The short story:**

I would really use the `typeof` operator.

**From isNaN() | JavaScript MDN:**

> The `isNaN()` function determines **whether a value is Not-A-Number or not.** `...` you may alternatively want to use `Number.isNaN()`, as defined in ECMAScript 6, or you can use `typeof` to determine if the value is Not-A-Number.

**Long story:**

*Tried the following in a node console.*

> A NaN also results from attempted coercion to numeric values of non-numeric values for which no primitive numeric value is available.

```
isNaN(123)           // false
isNaN(true)          // false
isNaN("123")         // false
isNaN({})            // true
isNaN(undefined)     // true
```

> In comparison to the global isNaN() function, Number.isNaN() doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number. This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert to NaN, but aren't actually the same value as NaN. This also means that only values of the type number, that are also NaN, return true.

```
Number.isNaN(undefined)      // false
Number.isNaN({})             // false
Number.isNaN(true)           // false
Number.isNaN(123)            // false
Number.isNaN(NaN)            // true
Number.isNaN(0/0)            // true
```

> The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

```
typeof(123)           // number
typeof("123")         // string
typeof(true)          // boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the isNaN is the right idea, but you should parse it first:

```
var myNumber = "006";
var myText = "1. This is not a number";    

Number.isNaN(Number.parseInt(myNumber)); // false
Number.isNaN(Number.parseInt(myText));   // true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).