# Checking datatypes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this small piece of code to check if a variable is a number or not, but does not work

```
var cost_value= 7777;
alert(cost_value);
if (typeof(cost_value) !== "number") {
    alert("not a number");//7777
 } else {
   alert("a number");
 }
```

But it will always alert as a "not a number"

```
change to if(jQuery.type(cost_value) !== "number"
```

Does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If anything, rubberduck-debug your code next time and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and ***Verifiable*** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is far too easy, so you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Comment: why do you need a solution given by Jquery when you have a stable JS solution? JQUERY is JAVASCRIPT

Comment: In your real code you're getting `cost_value` from a HTML element content or value?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced, because the author hat typeOf(costvalue) first. After a few seconds he/she editted his/her code.

Comment: You can try alert(typeof(cost_value)).

Comment: Reasons like this are why TypeScript makes things much easier.

Comment: Run your edited code. It alerts "a number". You are probably getting your variable assigned by some other input, as @Teemu described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan This is actually less helpful in this scenario. The appropriate action is to flag this question as off-topic (no-repro/typo).

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you could use [isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

```js
var cost_value = 7777;
if (!$.isNumeric(cost_value)) {
    alert("not a number");//7777
 } else {
   alert("a number");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: I've seen the first comment and your spelling error, so this problem is already fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that

```
var cost_value= 7777;
console.log(typeof(cost_value));
if (String(typeof(cost_value)) !== "number") {
    alert("not a number");//7777
 } else {
   alert("a number");
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/42m3b8u0/3/

Comment: I don’t see how this is helpful in any way.

Comment: No, the current code in the question already unexpectedly “works”. This answer just adds confusing fluff to the code without explanation. Anyway, no answers should even be added to this question because it’s based on a typo and therefore off-topic.