# isNaN() vs typecast(varString).tostring() = varString

Tags: javascript, string

After some string manipulation I am left with a 4 character string that I will call

```
varString
```

I need to see if this string could be interpreted as a number. I have been using

```
if(isNaN(Number(varString)) ==  false){return true}
```

but I am wondering if

```
if(Number("varString").toString() == varString){return true}
```

would be better.

Is one of these solutions more efficient, or more likely to catch non-numbers than the other? I have not found a difference while testing but I may have missed something. Alternative solutions welcome.

Edit in response to possible duplicate: I already have two ways of determining if something is a string or number. I am asking which method is better and why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Comment: In the first one, no need for the `== false` check. Just do `if(!isNaN(Number(varString)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be differences at least in these cases:

- With `"NaN"`

  ```
  isNaN(Number("NaN")) === false; // false
  Number("NaN").toString() === "NaN"; // true
  ```
- With `"-0"`

  ```
  isNaN(Number("-0")) === false; // true
  Number("-0").toString() === "-0"; // false
  ```
- With space padded numbers

  ```
  isNaN(Number(" 1 ")) === false; // true
  Number(" 1 ").toString() === " 1 "; // false
  ```
- With zero left-padded numbers

  ```
  isNaN(Number("01")) === false; // true
  Number("01").toString() === "01"; // false
  ```
- With numbers starting or ending with decimal point

  ```
  isNaN(Number(".5")) === false; // true
  Number(".5").toString() === ".5"; // false
  ```
- With huge or tiny numbers

  ```
  isNaN(Number("999999999999999999999")) === false; // true
  Number("999999999999999999999").toString() === "999999999999999999999"; // false
  ```
- With non-huge and non-tiny numbers in exponential form

  ```
  isNaN(Number("1e1")) === false; // true
  Number("1e1").toString() === "1e1"; // false
  ```
- With binary, octal or hex literals

  ```
  isNaN(Number("0xa")) === false; // true
  Number("0xa").toString() === "0xa"; // false
  ```

Answer (score 3):

The second method will prove wrong for some cases, since `Number` will convert numbers starting with `0`, but will save them in the form of a number, so a `toString` will not match the original string:

```js
document.write(Number("0123").toString() == "0123")
```

---

Go with

```
return !isNaN(varString)
```

(a variation of the first one, and you dont need to parse with `Number`).

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you are parsing the number from string and converting it back to string. Obviously, it is less efficient