# Vue3 v-model value mask/formatting (german number format)

Tags: vue.js, input, vuejs3, number-formatting

I have a simple vue component which has has an input and the related v-model.
What we want is to format/mask the value, the input should have the german number format (, and . switched (From `1,000,000.00` to `1.000.000,00`). The (raw) value inside the component on the other side should have the raw (englisch format) value `1,000,000.00`.

Or short: I need an input which shows the german number format, the raw value still should have the english format.

Thanks in advance

I already tried it with [maska](https://github.com/beholdr/maska) which shows the value correctly on the frontend, but the raw value is just an int instead of a float.

I also tried to use [vue-number-format](https://github.com/coders-tm/vue-number-format), but i always get `Vue is not defined` in the console.

I also searched on stackoverflow and found a few (older) workarounds with the `focus` and `blur` event, but this seems like a dirty implementation for me.

Comment: Check if this is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538110/how-to-format-numbers-in-vuejs

Comment: I don't think that helps, a few answers are filters which are removed in vue 3.
The other solutions are one way formatting, which is quite easy, but i need the formatting from english format -> german format (for the input) -> back to englisch format for the api.

Comment: try this formatter: https://igortrinidad.github.io/vue-number-format/