# How can I Avoid NaN,While adding numbers from Array in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

**While I get Inputs from text box,and adding those input if i leave space then my result comes with NAN.**

Comment: can you provide with your code !!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hard to see what you did wrong without the code. Our crystal balls are broken. Show sample input and expected output. Providing those details will result in a nice answer. Put effort into your question and people will put effort into the answers. Sounds like you need to check it is a number before you add.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad. Please take a look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site, particularly this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript

Comment: @DavidJawHpan    for (var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
     var sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(strSplit[i])
     }
     document.getElementById("resultStr").value = sum;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find if the entered text is a number or not and then try to add them.

you can use below snippet.

It is just to  give you the idea.

```js
var ToCheck=sometext;
var  IsNotaNumber=isNaN(ToCheck);//check both the inputs
if(!IsNotaNumber)
{
//add the numbers
}
```

Comment: @Cid agreed and i updated the answer. thanks :)