# How to check If the value of an input is number or string in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input

I want to check if the value of a type text input is number or string like this :

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(typeof value);
  }}
/>
```

But when I type text or number it console logs string in both cases .

How can I check if the value is number with input type text in react js ?

Comment: the value of a `<input>` tag with `type="text"` will always have the type `string` for the `value` prop

Comment: @Samathingamajig I don't want to use type number for some reason is there any other way to check the value type ?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Even if u use `type="number"`, the value of the input will be a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way will be to convert the string to a number and then check if it's valid. As the value of inputs is always a `string` even if you use `type="number"`, though it is good to use it if you just want numbers as the input.

You can use `isNaN(+value)`. Here `+` will convert a string to a number.

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(!isNaN(+value)); // true if its a number, false if not
  }}
/>
```

---

**Some test cases:**

```js
console.log(!isNaN(+"54"));
console.log(!isNaN(+"23xede"));
console.log(!isNaN(+"test"));
```

> **Note:** As mentioned this is a simple way, there can be workarounds to bypass this, for a robust solution you can have a look here: [Check whether variable is number or string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript/1303650)

Answer (score 3):

You can cast to number and then check if it's Nan

```
isNaN(parseInt('0')) // false
isNaN(parseInt('f')) // true
```

As noted in the comments parseInt() will return a number for a string with a number in it.  Using Number on the other hand will return Nan

```
isNaN(Number('55')) // false
isNaN(Number('55bob')) // true
```

Comment: `parseInt("56bob")` returns `56`, not `NaN`

Comment: @Samathingamajig Good point maybe a better idea to use Number("56bob")