# How can I get 'return True' by exponent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, nan, exponent, isnan

*First, I'm sorry I can't speak English well.*

I have some problems studying JS. I want to return true if the string is a Number.

If string is `"0x10", "0b10", "9843"` it work well (all return true).
And string like `"a463"` return false well.

But, when the string is a string with an exponent like `"1e43"...` it doesn't work well. (it's return false)
I want to return true when string with exponent.

```js
if (isNaN(s - 0)) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

I think have a problem with `if()`.

**So, How can I get `return true`, when the string is with exponent, like `"1e22", "13e7"`?**

Comment: `"34.12e5"-0 -> 3412000` are you sure your impl isn't working for that exponent notation?

Comment: You solution should work because string-to-number cast via `s - 0` or `+s` supports exponential numbers.

Comment: keep in mind this returns 'true' for space characters `' '`. A lot of discussion here: [Check whether variable is number or string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you redefining the grammar for numbers such that you are including exotic things like hex strings (`0xff`) and binary strings (`0b11111111`) but selectively removing just decimals with exponent parts (`2.55e2` or `255e0`)?  Do you also want to permit explicit octal strings (`0o377`) and legacy octal strings (`0377`)?  What about BigIntegers (`255n`) and what about strings like `Infinity`  or `Nan`?  _What do you have against exponent notation?_